# Replacing portion of the string using Regex in java

Tags: java, android

I have a long string. I want to replace all the matches with part of the matching regex (group).

For example:

link1/myapp/link2 or link1/maapp/link2

I want to consider "myapp" as well as "maapp" in my search string

can I create a regex for this ?

Comment: I suggest that you read the API docs for the regex package.

Comment: *"can I create a regex for this?"*; sure, what did you try so far?

Comment: I have given the answer below which worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @Code-Apprentice. Please find my observation below,

1). Use replaceAll() as it supports the regex and not the replace().

2). string.replaceAll("m[ya]app","");

Hope it helps